# Importing Date-datatype using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have many GB of data stored in PostgreSQL database and i need those to be imported into the MongoDB. I did this using CSV export and mongoimport.

There are columns like this '2011-06-25' in that CSV and it has been imported as string, not as MongoDate, so i cannot effectively search by date.

I've found this : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3AImportingInterestingTypes
but the example says, i need to use JSON structure for the file. Do i really need to export JSON file from PostgreSQL?

**If i do - how?**

**If i don't, how to export "MongoDate" through CSV?**

Comment: i guess it wouldn't be as fast as native mongoimport tool, which is crucial fact in case of large amount of data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your options:

- import the stuff as CSV and convert the data after the import to Date() (either using the mongo console or using a script written in your favorite language)
- import your data as JSON and using the $date descriptor for converting date strings into Date instances

Answer (score 21):

Actually the first option is pretty fast even with huge data. Here is an example query using the mongo console:

```
/usr/bin/mongo yourdbname --eval "db.yourcollectionname.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.yourdatefield = new ISODate(doc.yourdatefield);db.yourcollectionname.save(doc)});"
```

Comment: Looks like this is going to take a couple of hours on my collection of 65 million documents. I guess it is "pretty fast".

Comment: Now it looks like it is going to take something like 10 or 20 hours. Not so fast.

Comment: @Mika I was wondering if this approach would be practical for me, but my collection has ~130 million documents. Sigh...

Comment: I would remember that we ended up importing the documents from csv, which was really fast. Then we ran a query in mongodb to loop through all documents and convert the string date into real date object. That took a while, but it is a lot easier to work on the data once it is in the database. At least when compared to an error prone regex / sed command chain fired towards the csv before the import.

Comment: this is what i ended up doing, was a lot faster than iterating through in JS code.

Answer (score 2):

Write a script using your favorite language to import the data. It will allow you to control the data-type and apply structural changes to the data as well.

Generally you will find that the mapping of the data is not the same when converting from tabular data to a document database.

If you write a script you may also want to support running multiple copies (or threads) to improve the import speed.

Answer (score 2):

When possible, re-importing from the source CSV should be faster. For a relatively large dataset (130M objects, source CSV ~6GB), a `mongoimport` run took 40mins, but the `forEach` suggested by @webDEVILopers took 24h+ (at which point I canceled it).

To import from CSV and convert your date, I ran

```
mongoimport --db your-db-name --type csv --file your-file.csv --collection your-collection --fields timestamp.date\(2006-01-02\ 15:04:0
5.00000+00\),count.int32\(\), --columnsHaveType
```

The `.date()` part is tricky, you **have** to specify that particular date in your source format. So my timestamps were like "2018-02-03 12:09:23.00000+00", which meant formatting the reference date (Jan 2nd, 2006 15:04:05) in that format (as in command above). See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-columnshavetypes) for reference.

Comment: you actually put a date string into the `date(....)` field?

Comment: also i think your answer is cut off?

Comment: @dcsan yeah, you have to put in _that exact_ date (Jan 2nd, 2006 15:04:05) in date field, formatted to match what your dates look like in your dataset. it's quite bizzarre. Which part is cut off? The command section should scroll horizontally.

Comment: re cutoff: oh maybe there's an odd wraparound. OK i'll try that. weird :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a *little bit* late, but the `forEach` version above can be made faster by orders of magnitude by using `bulkWrite` instead of `save`, and write with **0.25ms** instead of **1.2ms** per document.

*Note: my data required cleaning up strings, but that doesn't have an effect on writing documents.*

Without `bulkWrite`, i.e. `save`:

```bash
mongo> i=0;
0
mongo> start= new Date();
ISODate("2023-05-15T07:20:30.231Z")
mongo> db.myCol.find().forEach( d => {
     if (typeof(d.timeslot)!="string"){ return; };
     d.timeslot= new ISODate(d.timeslot.replace(' UTC',''));
     db.myCol.save(d);
     i+= 1;
     if (i%1000==0) {
       end=new Date();
       diff= (end.valueOf()-start.valueOf());
       printjson({
         ms: diff,
         n: 1000,
         avg_ms: diff/1000
       });
       start=new Date();
     }
   });
{ "ms" : 12722, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 12.722 }
{ "ms" : 1163, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 1.163 }
{ "ms" : 1208, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 1.208 }
{ "ms" : 1183, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 1.183 }
{ "ms" : 1168, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 1.168 }
:
```

With `bulkWrite`:

```bash
mongo> blk=[];
[ ]
mongo> start= new Date();
ISODate("2023-05-15T07:27:16.882Z")
mongo> db.myCol.find().forEach( d => {
     if (typeof(d.timeslot)!="string"){ return; };
     blk.push({ updateOne: { filter: {_id:d._id }, update: { $set: { timeslot: new ISODate(d.timeslot.replace(' UTC','')) } } } });
     if (blk.length > 0 && blk.length%1000==0) {
       res=db.myCol.bulkWrite(blk);
       end=new Date();
       diff= (end.valueOf()-start.valueOf());
       printjson({
         ms: diff,
         n: res.matchedCount,
         avg_ms: diff/res.matchedCount
       });
       start=new Date();
       blk=[];
     }
   });
mongo> db.myCol.bulkWrite(blk);
{ "ms" : 9745, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 9.745 }
{ "ms" : 252, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 0.252 }
{ "ms" : 231, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 0.231 }
{ "ms" : 213, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 0.213 }
{ "ms" : 209, "n" : 1000, "avg_ms" : 0.209 }
:
```