# importing CSV file MongoDB with ISODate

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoimport, isodate

When I export my data from mongoDB I obtain the following file:

Everything is a string in the mongoDB except for the date that is ISODate.

```
123@123.com,sha1:64000:18:BTJnM903gIt5FNlSsZIRx1tLC9ErPJuB:9YVs800sgRPr1aaLj73qqnJ6,123,123,123@123.com,2017-04-28T09:20:07.480Z,cus_AYcVXIUf68nT52
```

If I import this file into MongoDB it import each value as String value. I need to parse the date as Date format, the rest can be string.

I've seen that there's an argument for MongoImport --columnsHaveTypes. I've tryed it without any result:

```
mongoimport -u test-p test --authenticationDatabase test -h localhost:30158 --db test--collection users --type csv --file users.csv --upsert --upsertFields username --fields username.string\(\),password.string\(\),cname.string\(\),sname.string\(\),mail.string\(\),creation.date\(\),validation.auto\(\),clients.string\(\),customer.string\(\) --columnsHaveTypes
```

I get this error:

```
Failed: type coercion failure in document #0 for column 'creation', could not parse token '2017-04-28T09:20:07.480Z' to type date
```

What I could do?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Summary: you need to provide the format in which the date will be presented.

From the mongoimport documentation on the [columnsHaveTypes parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-columnshavetypes), you can't just say `created.date\(\)` - you need to provide an argument, which is a template for the way the date is represented in the CSV. Apparently the way you do this is, in accordance with the [Go Language time.Parse function](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), by rendering a particular reference date in the format of your choice.

I think the reference date should be formatted like this:

```
2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z
```

So you need to change your mongoimport call to specify the date with the format template, like this:

```
creation.date\(2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z\)
```

Comment: For inattentive readers like me: the date *has* to be January 2nd, 2006, as shown above. It can't be the first date in your file or any other date.

Comment: dates in my csv file look like                                                  
`2018-01-08T00:00:00.000Z`                                                      the corresponding field in mongoimport defined as `Gmttime.date\(2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z\)`                                        Still getting `Failed: type coercion failure in document #0 for column 'Gmttime', could not parse token 'Gmttime' to type date`