# mongoexport with Date Range

Tags: mongodb

Having trouble with mongoexport seems it is failing in the query. If I remove the query the export works. Any help would be appreciated thanks.
Env MongoDB 3.2

I'm trying to find all records with field created >= 21-Dec-2015
Converted the date as suggested in prior post (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148648/adam-comerford)

```
> new Date(2015,11,21)*1
1450648800000
> new Date(1450648800000)
ISODate("2015-12-20T22:00:00Z")




 mongoexport -d MyDB -c MyCollection -q '{created:{$gte:new  Date(1450648800000)}}' --out C:\Test\myRecords.json
```

Results from export

```
PS C:\Users\Me> mongoexport -d MyDB -c MyCollection -q '{created:{$gte:new Date(1450648800000)}}' --out C:\Test\myRecords.json
2016-02-11T00:00:08.223+0200    connected to: localhost
2016-02-11T00:00:08.228+0200    exported 0 records
PS C:\Users\Me>
```

Comment: Take a look at your own output. If you are intending to get the range of UTC dates from the 21st December 2015 then that is not what was returned by your date constructor. Instead do `new Date("2015-12-21").valueOf()` to return the milliseconds value. Note the difference in the constructor usage.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the query below however the results still says exported  0 records. Anything wrong with this query  -q '{"created":{$gte: new Date(1450656000000)}}'  I am new to Mongo so maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the date was imported as a string in mongoimport once I applied the solution reccomended by webDEVILopers to convert the string to a date the export worked. (See [Importing Date-datatype using mongoimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475987/importing-date-datatype-using-mongoimport/14876386#14876386)). Once the field was converted to date the export worked properly.